# How to change a float variable from another script based on distance to it

Tags: scripting

This is technically 2 questions but I may as well kill 2 birds with 1 stone. In my game I want the cameras glitch filter effect to increase the closer it is to a gameobject. I have tried achieving this by using a waypoint script that i got and where it writes down the metres to the gameobject I thought I could update the glitches glitch effect accordingly. I have looked at many questions and forums about changing a float from another script but for some reason it still cant find the script. Both scripts are under the same object which is the camera. This should hopefully be one of my last questions for I have been asking alot lately. Any help would be deeply appreciated! Also the main part of the waypoint script that calls the color drift is at the bottom as well.
Here is the waypoint script:

```css
    // Indicator icon
    public Image img;
    // The target (location, enemy, etc..)
    public Transform target;
    // UI Text to display the distance
    public Text meter;
    // To adjust the position of the icon
    public Vector3 offset;

    private void Update()
    {
        // Giving limits to the icon so it sticks on the screen
        // Below calculations witht the assumption that the icon anchor point is in the middle
        // Minimum X position: half of the icon width
        float minX = img.GetPixelAdjustedRect().width;
        // Maximum X position: screen width - half of the icon width
        float maxX = Screen.width - minX;

        // Minimum Y position: half of the height
        float minY = img.GetPixelAdjustedRect().height;
        // Maximum Y position: screen height - half of the icon height
        float maxY = Screen.height - minY;

        // Temporary variable to store the converted position from 3D world point to 2D screen point
        Vector2 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(target.position + offset);

        // Check if the target is behind us, to only show the icon once the target is in front
        if (Vector3.Dot((target.position - transform.position), transform.forward) < 0)
        {
            // Check if the target is on the left side of the screen
            if (pos.x < Screen.width / 2)
            {
                // Place it on the right (Since it's behind the player, it's the opposite)
                pos.x = maxX;
            }
            else
            {
                // Place it on the left side
                pos.x = minX;
            }
        }

        // Limit the X and Y positions
        pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, minX, maxX);
        pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, minY, maxY);

        // Update the marker's position
        img.transform.position = pos;
        // Change the meter text to the distance with the meter unit 'm'
        meter.text = ((int)Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position)).ToString() + "m";
        if ((int)Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position))
        {
            AnalogGlitch.colorDrift + 0.001;
        }
    }
```

This is the other code which is analog glitch and the colorDift is at the bottom

```css
using UnityEngine;

namespace Kino
{
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
    [AddComponentMenu("Kino Image Effects/Analog Glitch")]
    public class AnalogGlitch : MonoBehaviour
    {
        
            #region Public Properties

            // Scan line jitter

            [SerializeField, Range(0, 1)]
            float _scanLineJitter = 0;

            public float scanLineJitter
            {
                get { return _scanLineJitter; }
                set { _scanLineJitter = value; }
            }

            // Vertical jump

            [SerializeField, Range(0, 1)]
            float _verticalJump = 0;

            public float verticalJump
            {
                get { return _verticalJump; }
                set { _verticalJump = value; }
            }

            // Horizontal shake

            [SerializeField, Range(0, 1)]
            float _horizontalShake = 0;

            public float horizontalShake
            {
                get { return _horizontalShake; }
                set { _horizontalShake = value; }
            }


            // Color drift

            [SerializeField, Range(0, 1)]
            public float _colorDrift = 0;

            public float colorDrift
            {
                get { return _colorDrift; }
                set { _colorDrift = value; }
            }
```

```
enter code here
```

enter code here

Comment: You don't appear to get the component you want, you just set a value to the class of it, and not a specific instance.

Comment: So I reference the main camera gameobject.MainCamera._colorDrift or
MainCamera._colorDrift or main camera.AnalogGlitch._colorDrift or gameobject.MainCamera.AnalogGlitch._colorDrift?...

Comment: If both components are part of the same gameobject, isn't it only a matter of using `getComponent<AnalogGlitch>`? (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

Comment: ok so I did

`AnalogGlitch Drift = gameObject.GetComponent<AnalogGlitch>();
        // Change the meter text to the distance with the meter unit 'm'
        meter.text = ((int)Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position)).ToString() + "m";
       if ((int)Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position))
        {
            Drift._colorDrift + 1;
        }`
this gets more errors then before... Im not sure if this is correct but yeah. I'm still a bit new to code.

Comment: By doing only `Drift._colorDrift + 1;` you will increment a number but you will not store it anywhere and it will not update any variable. You'll need to assign it: `Drift._colorDrift = Drift._colorDrift + 1;`. I see you have at least 20 rep across the network. If you have issues with programming, I suggest you hit us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development). It's a bit better suited for this kind of issue (with the back-and-forth).